# SQL Subqueries concatenation issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple subquery that works fine

```
SELECT id, Name, subset
 , (select count (1) from anotherTable where qid = someTable.id )
FROM someTable
```

the value "subset" is a string ie: 
"and (PreQ1 like '%A%') and ( PreQ2 like '%A%' or    PreQ2 like '%C%')"

And so I'd like to ConCatenate the subquery with the value subset like this:

```
SELECT id, Name, subset
 , exec  ( 'select count (1) from anotherTable where qid = someTable.id ' + subset)
 FROM someTable
```

.. but get a "Conversion failed" error

Comment: What you want is very difficult to implement. You want to execute a different SQL for each row dynamically. I guess you can get such a result for each row one by one, but not in a single set query

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to accomplish? A `view` that unions together various results might be more appropriate, depending on the number of subsets, how often they change, how many subsets of subsets (?!) you might want to query, ... .

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT s.id, s.Name, s.subset,
       (select cast(count(1) as varchar(255)) + s.subset
        from anotherTable a
        where a.qid = s.id
       )
FROM someTable s;
```

This does the concatenation within the subquery.  You can also put the `+ s.subset` outside the subquery.

Also note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks very much, but the output here basically executes the count(1) and concatenates the value in s.subset..

Comment: an example of what s.subset is would be "AND (PreQ1 like '%A%' ) AND (PreQ5 like '%A%' )".. which are basically stored "conditions" so I would need to execute ... select count(1) from anotherTable a where a.qid = s.id AND (PreQ1 like '%A%' ) AND (PreQ5 like '%A%' )